# Symfony 2.3 Installing SonataAdminBundle via composer

Tags: symfony, composer-php, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I'm trying to install sonataAdminBundle via composer, doing as in documentation

```
php composer.phar require sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle
```

Then typing version - dev-master

```
Please provide a version constraint for the sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle requirement: dev-master
```

And it goes....

```
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing sonata-project/block-bundle (2.2.7)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing sonata-project/exporter (1.3.2)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing sonata-project/jquery-bundle (1.8.3)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing knplabs/knp-menu (v1.1.2)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing knplabs/knp-menu-bundle (v1.1.2)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing sonata-project/admin-bundle (2.2.7)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle (dev-master 84aa85c)
    Cloning 84aa85cdb53dbab7204ece9510541f713102d297



  [RuntimeException]                                                                                                  
  Failed to clone https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle.git, git was not found, check that   
  it is installed and in your PATH env.                                                                               

  sh: 1: git: not found                                                                                               




require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--no-progress] [--no-update] [packages1] ... [packagesN]
```

There is error, it doesnt found..
I see there is sonata-project folder in /vendors/ which contains admin-bundle, block-bundle,  doctrine-orm-admin-bundle, exporter, jquery bundle  folders..

So everything is okay? 
But he doesnt found SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle. How can i fix this?

Thanks

Composer.json

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
        "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
        "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "dev-master"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.3-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the content of you `composer.json` file in your question.

Comment: added the content to main question

Comment: Maybe you should also install the [SonataAdminBundle](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/installation.html).

Comment: Is git installed? run `git --version` to check, because it looks like the other packages are download as a zip and unpacked on your pc (so no git needed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git executable does not exist, please install it...